# Ubuntu two users logged with same name

Tags: command-line, ssh, users, logout

I have a server and a ssh session, but it seems like I've pressed something and it was a shortcut so currently, when I do `w` it shows my other session (which I don't know how I opened). I closed my ssh client and accessed the shell via other method and it still showed 1 user logged. From what I read seems like I pressed accidentally some shortcut key and opened second terminal. My question is how do I close it? I tried exit, it just returned logged out and `users` or `w` still shows 2 users. Also, one of my users is `pts/0` other is `pts/1`. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you log in, or connect to sftp, a new user gets logged in.
Try it, if you open 10 terminals and connect to your server, you will have 10 users.

**But it's not a problem at all.**
Just imagine a production server with thousands of users logged in.

In short: Don't worry. Unless it's an unknown user, leave it.
In case it is, you should strenghten the security of your server.
And kick him out:
`w` will show you the sessions.
`ps faux | grep sshd` will let you find the unknown person by his pts.
`kill 12345` will kill the process with 12345 pid.

Comment: Well, thanks, no one else is logged in but I just want to close this terminal or whatever, I think I opened it via ````screen```` because when I do screen -r it shows one of them as attached.